# How should we tag off-topic questions?

Tags: support, tags, scope

I've been working on getting rid of some utterly useless tags and in the process have sometimes run into situations where the question is so far off topic that I can't find or imagine any tags that fit the question and do not themselves deserve destruction.

How should I retag such things? Do we need an "off-topic" tag for the purpose?

Comment: [meta-tag:meta-tags] like "off-topic" would better be avoided

Comment: @gnat, hypothetically, wouldn't it be better to have a question about social or economic classes tagged [tag:off-topic] than [tag:class]?

Comment: hypothetically, it unlikely would if you think of it. First off, re-tagging would hide them from _class_ tag regulars (who are well positioned to realize how much off-topic it is), possibly making it harder to close. Second, it would open doors for intentional or unintentional abusive schemes exploiting [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773)

Comment: When I'm burning tags, and removing the tag renders the question tagless because it's utterly off topic, I usually dump it into the [tag:language-agnostic] dustbin while it waits for deletion.  Sorry people who follow that tag :/

Comment: @Will, there are too many dustbins: [tag:image], [tag:internet], [tag:method], etc.

Answer (score 11):

You should be voting to close/delete these questions, and not really worrying about their tags.

Don't waste your time organizing the trash.  Just throw it out.

Comment: Won't the questions keep the tag alive?

Comment: @dfeuer Not if they're deleted, no.

Comment: Deleting questions is not so easy, especially when they have upvoted answers.

Comment: 3 delete votes isn't *that* hard.  The answers they have doesn't affect how hard it is, really.  Either way, you should be far more concerned about getting rid of the bad question than having a tag not be deleted.

Comment: Only users with 10,000 rep can cast them, and there's no way to flag requesting them. That limits things somewhat.

Comment: @dfeuer - there's a Delete Vote chat room, I'm not sure if the "10K+ only" is a redundant requirement of being able to vote, or if only 10K+ members are supposed to chat in there, but there is http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67850/delete-voters.  Send some stuff our way, we like deleting things.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables "This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added. "