# Should off-topic tags be added to questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

I was just doing a little sweep of questions tagged [appstore-approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appstore-approval), closing/deleting/retagging as appropriate.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981043/drop-ipad-support-for-ios-app?noredirect=1#comment53903868_32981043) where the tag had actually been *added* by a user who has close voted:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's review policies.

A short exchange followed:

> @rmaddy, I wouldn't add the appstore-approval tag given that it's off topic. We don't really need tags for things we don't want on the site. :D –  James Webster
>
> @JamesWebster That's the point. The question is off-topic because it is about app store approval. –  rmaddy

I respect rmaddy, regularly active and lots of good answers, however I disagree with them here. I understand the reasoning, adding the tag adds another way to point out the question is off-topic; I just don't think it's needed.

I would argue against adding tags about off-topic questions, preferring just to close and delete. Is there a previous example of this? What is the consensus?

Comment: I agree with you. I predict a *Burninate app-store-approval* meta question popping up in the next few weeks.

Comment: @DaveZych Like [these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=app-store-approval)? (Not _exact_ matches, but coverage.) It seems to me that a burnination clean-up would be made more effective by tagging off-topic questions on the subject so they get considered as a group.

Comment: Having questions tagged in a group is essential to burnination, otherwise those off-topic questions are then spread across the site without any easy way of closing them in a group.

Comment: "That question is off topic" ***"How can it be off topic! There's a TAG for it!!!"***  You're only encouraging them.

Comment: Related: [Should a question be closed as off topic even though a tag exists?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270744) "If the tag is one that couldn't possibly be applied to an on-topic question, come to Meta and suggest burnination" Also: [How should we tag off topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284370)

Comment: @DaveZych Wasn't this burninated a year or so ago?  I remember participating in a cleanup that involved editing lots of questions to remove a store-related tag so it could be deleted.

Comment: From 2014: [Nuke the approval tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276924/nuke-the-approval-tag)

Answer (score 4):

Does adding the tag better categorize the question?
If yes, that's all there is to it.

Is the whole tag bad?
Probably, but that's a different question.
Add/Find an appropriate burninate-request if you think so.

If there is a way to properly tag a question, is it on-topic?
No, that has no bearing on the site's scope.
New tags are added and bad tags pruned by the community as seems appropriate.

Comment: Would you still think the same if the question was: "is there an adjective form of jubilee?" and I added the tag "grammar"? (Pulling a random question of mine from elu as an example of another question that is off topic).

Comment: @JamesWebster - Are you just trolling? I don't see how a completely off-base example helps the discussion.

Comment: @Mogsdad, an extreme example perhaps. But I have the same arguments for both types of question.